Manhwa where a witch accidently wakes up a crown prince
I'm looking for a manhwa where a witch accidently wakes up a crown prince. The crown prince had some issues with waking up or something that anyone couldn't wake him up (I read it months ago) but after the witch woke him he started looking for her. The witch is like thousands years old and lives in a forest. After the prince found her he proposed but she rejected.
That's all I remember. Back then it was newly releasing. It was a historical manhwa no reincarnation or isekai.

Di Gui Huang Fei Bu Hao Dang aka Little Witch Wife, Don't Run Away From Me looks to be a match.


Clara is a renowned romance witch. When the crown prince fell into a perpetual sleep, people speculated that she casted a spell on him because of bitterness borne out of infatuation with him. But it was the crown prince who fell in love with her at first sight when she snuck into the palace, and insisted on marrying her! So one day, the crown prince led his troops into the forest: “Clara, I’m here to take you home.”

I did a quick peek at the first chapter or so. She is an immortal who has been over a hundred years in her house in the forest, reading romance novels.
Found with a search for manhwa witch wakes up sleeping prince
